# Computing the Dieudonné module of $\mu_p$ from Fontaine's Witt Covector

Tags: nt.number-theory, group-schemes, p-adic, dieudonne, p-divisible-group-schemes

In *[Groupes $p$-divisibles sur les corps locaux](http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_1977__47-48__1_0/)*, Fontaine introduced a uniform construction of Dieudonné modules through the definition of the Witt covector. Consider a perfect field $k$ of characteristic $p$ and a finite $k$-algebra $R$. Fontaine presented a group functor

$$\operatorname{CW}(R) = \{(\dotsc, a_{-3}, a_{-2}, a_{-1}) \mid a_i\in R\},$$

where for some (negative) integer $r$, the ideal generated by $\{a_n \mid n < r\}$ is nilpotent. The addition is the usual Witt vector addition, which is well-defined due to the nilpotency condition. This functor is obviously represented by an affine group scheme, so pro-represented by a formal $p$-group. He gave the following theorem:

> **Theorem (Fontaine).** The Dieudonné module of a finite group scheme $G$ is given by
> $M(G) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\text{formal-groups}}(G, \operatorname{CW}).$

For a constant group scheme $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the homomorphisms correspond to group homomorphisms on $k$-points. If $G = \alpha_p = \operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^p)$, then these homomorphisms are represented by $(\dotsc, 0, 0, ax)$ for some $a \in k$. For $G = \mu_p$, we know that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\text{formal-groups}}(\mu_p, \operatorname{CW}) = k$. However, I cannot find a single explicit homomorphism.

> **Question 1.** How to represent the homomorphisms from $\mu_p=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^p-1)$ to $\operatorname{CW}$ in terms of the coordinates
> $\operatorname{CW}(\mu_p) = \{(\dotsc, a_{-3}, a_{-2}, a_{-1}) \mid a_i\in k[x]/(x^p-1)\}$?

There is an exact sequence

$$ 0 \rightarrow \varinjlim \mu_{p^n} \rightarrow \operatorname{CW} \xrightarrow{1-V} \operatorname{CW} \rightarrow 0, $$

which appears to be analogous to the Artin–Schreier sequence

$$ 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Q}_p \rightarrow \operatorname{CW} \xrightarrow{1-F} \operatorname{CW} \rightarrow 0. $$

Let $A$ denote the kernel of the map $\operatorname{CW} \xrightarrow{1-V} \operatorname{CW}$. By definition, $V$ acts trivially on $A$, so $F$ acts on $A$ as multiplication by $p$. Thus, every element of $A[p^n](R)$ can be represented as $(\dotsc, a, a, a)$ for some $a\in R$ satisfying $a^{p^n}=0$.

Therefore, $A[p^n]$ is represented by $k[x]/(x^p)$. Considering the actions of $V$ and $F$, it becomes evident that $A[p^n]$ is isomorphic to $\mu_{p^n}$.

> **Question 2.** How can we explicitly represent the isomorphism $\mu_p$ with $A[p] = \ker(\operatorname{CW} \xrightarrow{1-V} \operatorname{CW})[p]$  in terms of the coordinates $A[p](\mu_p) = \{(\dotsc, a, a, a) \mid a \in k[x]/(x^p-1)\}$?

Comment: TeX note: if you want some math set in `\text` or `\mathrm` because it is serving as an operator, then it is likely that `\operatorname` is better.  For example, compare `\text{Spec } k[x]/(x^p - 1)`, which requires an explicit space, to `\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^p - 1)`, which handles it automatically.  I edited accordingly.  (Also, you can define frequently used `\operatorname`s as commands, like `\DeclareMathOperator\CW{CW}\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}`.)